# Transactional Messaging API Reporting

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking for where the transactional messaging API is reporting with email tracking (opens, clicks, CTR, etc...), however, I am not finding any documentation or anywhere within SFMC where this is currently being tracked.

Any insights on this?

Comment: You will receive a token to check the status of each message as well!

Comment: dumb Q, but how can I use the token to check the status?

Answer (score 1):

Transactional Messaging sends are still recorded in the [dataviews](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) such as `_open` & `_click` and they also also included in the [standard reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_standard_reports.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks! The weird thing that is happening is that I don't have any visibility of the email send in any of my tracking folders so I'm not sure what the JobID is to find it in dataviews. I receive the email via the API but from there I can't see the send in SFMC.

Comment: @McdonaldZip you can query the _job dataview by email name

Comment: thanks, i'll try that!